# Add data in 3/4 tables from one controller

Tags: cakephp

I have following tables

User hasmany Restaurant

Restaurant hasmany(RestaurantCuisine, RestaurantAddress,FavoriteRestaurant,RestaurantFeature, RestaurantReview)

RestaurantAddress has many city

RestaurantCuisine has many cuisine

My question is can I add data to all the tables from UserController??

If I can then, how?

please refer me to the specific document where i can find the information. many times I read save your data from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html and tried many things (saveAll, saveAssociated)
but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you can specify which models to use. This is done with the property $uses.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Users', 'Restaurant') // etc
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html (near the bottom)

I hope this answers your question, if not get back to me.

Cory

Comment: Thx but thats not enough man. I am trying to save data in all the tables using saveAssociated and SaveAll it is only letting me add information in direct connected tables inspite of using 'deep' = TRUE; in saveAssociated.